# Disadvantages of using multiple versions of OpenGL in LWJGL?

Tags: opengl, java, lwjgl

So, I'm trying to figure out LWJGL, and my goal is to use OpenGL 3.2 (because pretty shaders are pretty).  But in every tutorial I can find for LWJGL, they import a bunch of different OpenGL versions and use them at the same time.  For example, [this one](http://www.lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=The_Quad_with_DrawArrays) imports GL11, GL15, GL20, and GL30 and uses functions from all of them.  This seems intuitively like it would be messy and generally a bad idea.  Besides the normal disadvantages of using deprecated functions, is there any particular reason not to do this?  Could it affect performance in any way?  Is there a potential for errors and odd behavior to occur?

Also, if possible, does anyone have an example of LWJGL written only using GL32?  I've found C++ code samples that do this, but I'm not too familiar with C++, so it's difficult for me to translate.

Answer (score 5):

LWJGL prefaces all core functions and enumerators with the OpenGL version that those functions were introduced in. So `glBindBuffer`, a function introduced in OpenGL version 1.5, is called `GL15.glBindBuffer`.

That's just how it works. It's not really importing "a bunch of different OpenGL versions"; it's just using the version those functions/enumerators was introduced in as a "namespace" scope.

That way, if you're writing to a specific OpenGL version, it's easier to prevent yourself from using functions that aren't available in that version. Of course, OpenGL [core extensions](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Extensions#Core_Extensions) kinda confound this notion.

Answer (score 4):

As Nicol Bolas said, the version number corresponds directly to the version number were a symbol, function or constant was introduced.

It's probably impossible to write a working application using only the GL32, or any one namespace for that matter (maybe apart from GL11). For instance look at this snippet from my game:

```
    this.fbo = GL30.glGenFramebuffers();
    GL30.glBindFramebuffer(GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);

    GL30.glFramebufferTexture2D(GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL30.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, this.fboImg, 0);
    GL30.glFramebufferTexture2D(GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL30.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, this.fboTileCoordsImg, 0);
    GL30.glFramebufferTexture2D(GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL30.GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, this.depthImg, 0);

    int status = GL30.glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
    if (status != GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("Framebuffer creation failed with code: " + status);
    }

    IntBuffer scratchBuffer = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(2);
    scratchBuffer.put(0, GL30.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
    scratchBuffer.put(1, GL30.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1);
    GL20.glDrawBuffers(scratchBuffer);
```

I'm using glFramebufferTexture2D which came with OpenGL30, but I need the constant GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D. Later on I need to call glDrawBuffers which comes from GL20. Nothing fishy here; I just an older function to do a newer thing, like the OpenGL docs tell me to. Besides, I don't really have a choice :)

What you should worry about are deprecated functions, like these: glBegin, glEnd,    glVertex*, glNormal*, glTextCoord*, glTranslate*, glRotate*, glScale*, glLoadIdenity, glModelViewMatrix... etc. Generally everything that uses fixed pipeline or the matrix stack.

If you are worried if you are using deprecated functionality, you can force LWJGL to create a strictly core profile rendering context with an appropriate openGL version by passing an appropriate ContextAttribs to Display.create.